# Why does IE7 specify a mime-type of image/pjpeg rather than just image/jpeg?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, file-upload, jpeg

When uploading a file (jpeg) via a form in IE7 I am seeing a mime-type of "image/pjpeg" instead of "image/jpeg" (as I see in Firefox or similar).  It's easy enough to work around this problem, but I'm just wondering why IE7 is behaving differently in this case?

Comment: I had visitors upload images and test if it is an acceptable type, of course pjpeg was not in my allowed_format_list and was a real pain to identify this problem. I seen it on IE 7 and 8.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe it's because the JPEG you're working with is a progressive JPEG, which has a different mime-type.

Comment: I think it's just image/jpeg and image/pjpeg (for JPEGs).  I'm not even sure if using a mime of "image/pjpeg" is even standard, but when has that stopped anyone? :)

Comment: Is there any reason why IE7 makes this distinction though - whereas FF etc doesn't?

Comment: Apparently the IE team thought it was different enough to call out with a separate mime type.  But they were probably wrong in doing so:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.infosystems.www.authoring.images/msg/7706603e4bd1d9d4?hl=en

Comment: Ah, so it's because (historically) image/jpeg as a mime-type was around before progressive JPEGs themselves, so not all browsers that said they could accept image/jpeg could deal with progressive JPEGs.

Answer (score 27):

IE can upload all .jpeg files as its hack MIME type 'image/pjpeg' regardless of whether or not they're actually progressive.

Don't rely on the MIME type supplied in a file upload, there is every chance it could be wrong for a variety of reasons including this one.

Comment: Another stackoverflow.com question/answer concerning the same:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200912/what-is-the-difference-between-image-x-citrix-pjpeg-and-image-pjpeg

Answer (score 24):

Because Microsoft likes to violate standards. There's no such MIME type as image/pjpeg.  See for yourself:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image

The correct MIME type for JPEG is image/jpeg, progressive or not.

Comment: The link above is correct but did slightly change to refer to the paragraph : http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image

Answer (score 16):

There is same problem with png:

IE7: image/x-png
Normal browsers: image/png

;)

Comment: That's slightly different: the x- prefix is standardised as a namespace for unregistered MIME types, so this isn't violating the standard.  But still, it ought to use image/png.